# How to update password in SDL Tridion if SQL Server password is updated

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1

I am not able to login into the Tridion 2013 sp1 as my SQL Server password is changed, even I updated the password in Tridion MMC but even then its not working.

So please some one suggest/guide me that where I need to update that password in Trdion, so that CME will able to connect again with SQL server?

Comment: Did you restart the COM+ application and Tridion services after making your change, if so, tried a reboot of the server?

Comment: @Bart: I restart the server many times, as well services.

Comment: The CM database password is stored in the MMC snap-in under Database settings, if you have changed that accordingly, then you should be good to go. If not it might help to edit your question and supply some more information.

Comment: Do you know which component can't connect? For some of the add-ons passwords are stored in a separate location

Comment: Are you able to connect and open your CM db from SQL Server management Studio using the credentials you entered in MMC.

Comment: I am able to connent directly inot the SQL Server and also from from my local machine. even able to login onto the CME but getting error when click on COntent Explorer tab on right side of CME

Comment: Could you check in the Event Log for Tridion on the CMS server and see what error is getting logged there and share here

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments already, verify that you can connect to the database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or from Visual Studio.

If you can't, review the user created in SQL Server.
This video shows how to create a user in SQL Server, in your case, you should connect with the account "sa" and change the password for the existing user, but the video gives you an idea of how to access the users in SQL Server.
If you are in a development environment, you can change the password of the CM user and after update the config to ensure both are the same.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbd1aOt8H94

If you don't have the credentials for connect with 'sa' account, double check with the DBA team and confirm that user/pwd is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is resolved.

There is one more place where we need to change that password and that is Audience manager password along with database password in MMC.

So after changing the encripted password of Audience Manager, CME is start working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to login into the Tridion 2013 sp1 as my SQL Server password is changed

is an assumption that the two problems are related; are you sure they are? What are the error messages in the event log (you should have many when Tridion cannot connect to the database)?

As comments/posts correctly state the Tridion CM components connect to the CM database using the configuration in Tridion.ContentManager.config (in the config subfolder of your Tridion installation) which is normally managed via the MMC snap-in (the database configuration is encrypted so you cannot directly edit it).

Without any additional information it is virtually impossible to troubleshoot this problem (could be as far fetched as the MMC updating the "wrong" Tridion.ContentManager.config file)...